# Filtering query by date built from integers

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedure

I am trying to make a stored procedure and pass some parameters for filtering. As soon as filtering is in horizon, code has to be as generic as possible with as few as possible `if`, `else`, etc.

How could I make this more readable? Can I use functions for this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Stats] @network VARCHAR(9) = NULL, 
                                               @name    VARCHAR(100) = NULL, 
                                               @version VARCHAR(15) = NULL, 
                                               @year    INT = NULL, 
                                               @month   INT = NULL,
                                               @day INT = NULL,
                                               @from DATE = null,
                                               @to DATE = null
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SET nocount ON;

          DECLARE @fromYear INT = NULL;
      SET @fromYear = CASE WHEN @from IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(year, @from) END

          DECLARE @fromMonth INT = NULL;
      SET @fromMonth = CASE WHEN @from IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(month, @from) END

          DECLARE @fromDay INT = NULL;
      SET @fromDay = CASE WHEN @from IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(day, @from) END

          DECLARE @toYear INT = NULL;
      SET @toYear = CASE WHEN @to IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(year, @to) ELSE @fromYear END

          DECLARE @toMonth INT = NULL;
      SET @toMonth = CASE WHEN @to IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(month, @to) ELSE @fromMonth END

          DECLARE @toDay INT = NULL;
      SET @toDay = CASE WHEN @to IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(day, @to) ELSE @fromDay END


      SELECT GS.[contractaddress], 
             GS.[network], 
             GS.[rounds], 
             GS.[sessions], 
             GS.[handle], 
             GS.[hold], 
             GS.[year], 
             GS.[month], 
             GS.[day], 
             G.[name], 
             G.[version],
             DATEFROMPARTS(GS.[Year], GS.[Month], GS.[Day]) as [Date]
      FROM   [dbo].[gamestatsdaily] AS GS 
             INNER JOIN [dbo].[game] AS G 
                     ON GS.contractaddress = G.[contractaddress] 
      WHERE  ( @network IS NULL 
                OR ( GS.network = Upper(@network) ) ) 
             AND ( @name IS NULL 
                    OR ( GS.[contractaddress] IN (SELECT [contractaddress] 
                                                  FROM   [dbo].[game] 
                                                  WHERE  [name] = @name 
                                                         AND [version] = 
                                                             @version 
                                                         AND [network] = 
                                                             @network) 
                       ) ) 
             AND ( @year IS NULL OR GS.[Year] = @year )
             AND ( @month IS NULL OR GS.[Month] = @month )
             AND ( @day IS NULL OR GS.[Day] = @day )
             AND ( @from IS NULL OR ( GS.[Year] <= @fromYear AND @toYear >= GS.[Year] AND GS.[Month] <= @fromMonth AND @toMonth >= GS.[Month] AND GS.[Day] <= @fromMonth AND @toMonth >= GS.[Day]))

      ORDER  BY GS.[year] ASC, 
                GS.[month] ASC, 
                GS.[day] ASC 
  END
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Here is the revised SQL I came up with

Below this code is a list of tips for writing better SQL.

---

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Stats] 
      @network VARCHAR(9) = NULL
    , @name VARCHAR(100) = NULL
    , @version VARCHAR(15) = NULL
    , @year INT = NULL
    , @month INT = NULL
    , @day INT = NULL
    , @from DATE = NULL
    , @to DATE = NULL
AS

BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        WITH
        contract_address_list
        AS
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                [contractaddress]
            FROM 
                [dbo].[game]
            WHERE 
                1=1
                AND [name] = @name
                AND [version] = @version
                AND [network] = @network
        )
        SELECT 
              GS.[contractaddress]
            , GS.[network]
            , GS.[rounds]
            , GS.[sessions]
            , GS.[handle]
            , GS.[hold]
            , GS.[year]
            , GS.[month]
            , GS.[day]
            , G.[name]
            , G.[version]
            , [Date] = DATEFROMPARTS(GS.[Year], GS.[Month], GS.[Day])
        FROM 
            [dbo].[gamestatsdaily] AS GS
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[game] AS G ON GS.[contractaddress] = G.[contractaddress]
            LEFT JOIN contract_address_list AS CAL ON CAL.[contractaddress] = GS.[contractaddress]
        WHERE 
            1=1
            AND (@name IS NULL OR CAL.[name] IS NOT NULL)
            AND (@network IS NULL OR (GS.network = UPPER(@network)) )
            AND (@year IS NULL OR GS.[Year] = @year )
            AND (@month IS NULL OR GS.[Month] = @month )
            AND (@day IS NULL OR GS.[Day] = @day )
            AND (
                @from IS NULL
                OR (
                        GS.[Year] >= DATEPART(year, @from)
                    AND GS.[Year] <= COALESCE(DATEPART(year, @to), DATEPART(year, @from))
                    AND GS.[Month] >= DATEPART(month, @from)
                    AND GS.[Month] <= COALESCE(DATEPART(month, @to), DATEPART(month, @from))
                    AND GS.[Day] >= DATEPART(day, @from)
                    AND GS.[Day] <= DATEPART(day, @to)
                    )
                )
        ORDER BY 
              GS.[year] ASC
            , GS.[month] ASC
            , GS.[day] ASC

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
                [ErrorNumber] = ERROR_NUMBER()
            , [ErrorSeverity] = ERROR_SEVERITY()
            , [ErrorState] = ERROR_STATE()
            , [ErrorProcedure] = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
            , [ErrorLine] = ERROR_LINE()
            , [ErrorMessage] = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH

END
```

---

#### Tips for your SQL

1. For formatting, I would download the following tool, [Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TaoKlerks.PoorMansT-SqlFormatterSSMSVSExtension) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter). I use it when I have to edit other developer's code.

> Here are the settings I used

[image: screenshot]

2. I would put the commas in front to clearly define new columns. Versus code wrapped in multiple lines. It also makes trouble-shooting code easier.
3. If you put `1=1` at the top of a `WHERE` condition, it enables you to freely change the rest of the conditions when debugging a query. The SQL query engine will end up ignoring the `1=1` so it should have no performance impact. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242822/9059424)
4. If you use [common table expressions (CTE)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in your SQL it helps with documentation. The expression name can then let other developers know why you used that expression e.g. `contract_address_list` or `active_projects`.
5. Use the [COALESCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to evaluate the expression in the WHERE clause for the `DATEPARTS`.
6. I find it more convenient to see column alias's referenced from the left side e.g. `, [Date] = DATEFROMPARTS(GS.[Year], GS.[Month], GS.[Day])`
7. Avoid using keywords as object names. [Microsoft Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
8. Check the [Estimated Execution Plan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to check the performance of the query by pasting both SQL statements in a query window.

Here's an example.

[image: screenshot]